# can I link a CSS selector to an already defined CSS class?

Tags: css, selector

I have an external CSS file that defines a class, like so

```
.h { font-family = ...;
     etc = asf;
   }
```

In a HTML document, I refer to this CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="the.css">
```

Now, I'd like to have the first `<td>`s rendered with the characteristics of `.h`. Is this somehow possible with something like

```
td:nth-child(1) {
  @use(".h")
}
```

Comment: You can not do with pure css. Try Sass or Less instead.

Comment: Why don't you write a define a css for `td:nth-child(1) {}` in your current html file (this will overwrite the previous from the css file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using SASS or LESS

http://sass-lang.com/

Using SASS you can define a mixin and variables that you can reuse in other parts of the stylesheet.

Take a look at the SASS guide

http://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: this should be a comment